# What is the longest recorded "chainsplit" in bitcoin?

Tags: blockchain-fork, history

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin_network) has this nice image:

[image: Blockchain]

where green is the genesis block, black is the best chain and purple are stale chaintips. What is the longest stale chaintip ever recorded?

Comment: A note on terminology: "off-chain" refers systems that work without publishing every interaction to the blockchain. Examples for that are the Lightning Network and sidechains. The term you're looking for here is "chainsplit", "blockchain fork", or "stale chaintip". I'll edit your question for clarity.